# Can I have a cross-platform framework for OS X and tvOS?

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks, tvos

I am writing a tvOS app. Up to now I was developing the code as an OS X framework with a prototyping OS X app.

Now I would like to add the production tvOS app into the mix, *keeping the OS X prototype*. Which means I need the framework to be built both for OS X and tvOS. This should not be a problem in the principle, since I only use frameworks available on both platforms.

Is it possible to build a cross-platform framework? What settings do I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's commonly done.  Create a new Xcode target, targetting tvOS, and add the same source files as the OSX target.

If you need to include/exclude/change code or behaviour at compile time then you need to `#import <TargetConditionals.h>`.

Comment: Thanks! That’s what I am doing at the moment. Is there a solution without having a separate target for each platform?

Comment: @zoul I don't believe so.  What's the issue with creating separate targets?

Comment: Nothing much. I guess I would rather add one option to an existing target than add yet another target and then think about which files belong where twice.